# pass existing context to my setContext react hook (JS question)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, currying, use-context

My current context with a method to set the updated context looks like this:

```
export const AppContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentAppContext, setCurrentAppContext] = useState(initApp)

  const setAppContext = values => {
    setCurrentAppContext(values)
  }

  return <AppContext.Provider value={{ appContext: currentAppContext, setAppContext }}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>
}
```

and I set the new context in a component like so:

```
export default function Settings() {
  const { appContext, setAppContext } = useContext(AppContext)

  const func = ({ accountId }) => {
      setAppContext({
        ...appContext,
        accountId: accountId,
      })
    },
  })
  return <></>
}
```

**But I would prefer to do just** `setAppContext((currentContext) => ({...currentContext, accountId: accountId}))` like we do in the `useReducer` hook `useReducer(state => state.item)` kind of thing. Is this possible, if so, how would I write it?

Comment: Does this fit your demand? Just provide `dispatch` from `React.useReducer` rather than `setState`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set function returned from `useState()` allows you to pass a function in just like this, so actually no change to my code was necessary to allow this to happen, **it already works**!